MyPy inference issue: decorator behavior unclear, complains about None
I Have the following decorator to assign default values to data if none are provided to the function.when running mypy I get this error:
error: Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type "list[int] | None"; expected "Sized". It is like mypy cannot infer the behavior of the decorator.

def default_value(func: Optional[Callable[..., Any]] = None,flags: Optional[list[str]] = None) -> Callable[..., Any]:
    def decorator(func2: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[..., Any]:
                called_signature = inspect.signature(func2)

            
        @wraps(func2)
        def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Callable[..., Any]:
            args = called_signature.bind(*args, **kwargs)
            args.apply_defaults()
            new_args_dict = orig_args.arguments
            if flags is None:
                new_args_dict["data"] = [0,0,0]
            elif "Ones" in flags:
                new_args_dict["data"] = [1,1,1]
            else:
                new_args_dict["data"] = [1,0,1]
             
            return cast(Callable[..., Any], func2(data))
        return decorator
     if func:
       return default_value(func)
     return default_value


#example usage — this is where the error is raised
@_Decorators.default_value(flags=["Ones"])
def testing(data: Optional[Union[list[int], int]] = None,
        num: int = 3,
    ) -> int:
    if isinstance(data, int):
        data = [i for i in range(num)]
    res= len(data)+ num
    return res


It can't: calling inspect.signature is a dynamic effect. The return value isn't available for static analysis of the code.

I see, so I can only  use #type- ignore i guess

In any event, you can modify testing directly by assigning to testing.__defaults__; no need to wrap it. (By the way, decorator defines wrapper without actually using it anywhere. Did you mean for wrapper to call func2 and for decorator to return wrapper?)

Regardless of default-value injection, len(data) is never going to work if it's hinted as a union involving int or None, because neither of those has a length. You need type-narrowing inside the function so that len(data) is only called once you've ruled out data being an int or None.

I added some lines at the end that I forgot to copy I hope now it is clearer what is happening with the wraper and the decorator. Does it make sense to you now?

I do not want to  use if none to do something because I know in runtime it will never be None so I could use if not None and then use the len(data). For int yes I can create a list so I can have an if statement before. I will added in the example

There are really two questions here though: 1) Why does testing need to take a list or an int in the first place, and why not just write def testing(data: list[int] | int  = cast(list[int], [1,1,1]), num: int = 3) -> int: ... instead of bothering with a decorator?

I have in mind to make the decorator more complex in the future and using different flags for various functions. This is a very simplified test.

This decorator already looks more complicated than the problem it's supposedly trying to solve.

"It is like mypy cannot infer the behavior of the decorator." I think it's more like it doesn't inspect the usage of the function. The undecorated function still exists somewhere and could conceivably be called with None as argument.
